# Need Assistance with Symfony 2.7 creating first page

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to learn the Symfony framework and struggling with it.  The instructions are not very helpful or assume I know a lot more than I know.  I am just trying to create a single web page with proper route and controller.  I have been googling to find answers and made some progress but no luck yet.  Right now I just have the standard install of Symfony with just default bundles etc.  I created a project called "gtest3" and chose PHP for it...

I am not sure where I put the new route in (what file) or maybe it needs to be put in more than one file?

I found the "routing.yml" file which seems that is where I need to put it...

here is what is in there right now:

```
gtest3:
    resource: "@gtest3Bundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    prefix:   /


app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

I am guessing I need to add something to this and put the location/filename of the controller?  I have tried doing this a few ways and just get errors.

There is also the "routing.php" file that is referenced in the above code.  I am not sure if this is the "controller" or if it is an additional piece of the "route".  Here is the code from that file:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();

$collection->add('gtest3_homepage', new Route('/hello/{name}', array(
'_controller' => 'gtest3Bundle:Default:index',
)));

return $collection;
```

I am not sure what if anything I would add here.
Finally - there is the "DefaultConroller.php" file I found as well which may also be the controller.  I dont think I need to include the code of that file here.

So - all I am trying to do is create a route of maybe "/gman" and then have the controller just echo something on the page.  Super basic stuff.  And I cannot figure out how to get this going.

Can anyone help with this?  Thanks so much...

Comment: What instructions are you following? Symfony's documentation is generally pretty comprehensive. Here's the documentation to [create your first page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html). Have you seen this? Additionally, how did you create your bundle? The symfony console makes this easy with `app/console generate:bundle`. This creates a project bundle and adds all of the config, routing, updates the AppKernel etc.

Comment: Thanks Darragh but those are the instructions I was trying to follow; and nowhere does it say exactly how to code the route and what file it should be in etc.  It does give example code for a controller; if it should be in its own file or if you add it to another; and where it is located etc...

Comment: By the way, is that the actual indentation in your `routing.yml` file?

Comment: uh no; I just corrected the code above with the proper indentation.  I am not sure on this but it seems that the config.yml says to use routing.yml file; but then the routing.yml file says to use routing.php; so it seems any new routes will need to be added to the routing.php file; would you agree?

Comment: You have AppBundle inside default installation, and you can see where is controller (Folder name cannot be more specific) and how it looks like.

Comment: You posted route files shows a type of annotation.  So your route information actually goes in your controller.  One of the more confusing aspects of Symfony is that there are a number of ways to do the same thing.  Keep rereading the "create your first page" link.  Eventually it might start to make sense.

Comment: thanks for everyone's help; have made some progress but no winner yet; need to stop for tonight but back on this tomorrow as it is very important for me.  all the best, G

Comment: thanks guys - I succeeded in creating a page; have a lot of other things to figure out so will be working on those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your routes in three ways, either by using yml files, xml files, or by using a php file. This is [documented behaviour](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

You are from the looks of your `routing.yml` trying to set up a php version. I would not recommend it, and instead use configuration over coding the routing.

The annotation example would look like:

Adding a controller:

```
namespace Gtest3Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class Gtest3Bundle extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
}
```

And add in your `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
gtest3:
    resource: "@Gtest3Rights/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /what-ever-you-want
```

You can check what kind of routes you have defined by using:

```
./app/console router:debug
```

If it doesn't appear hear, you have something misconfigured.

Please be advised that your bundle names breaks the convention of how bundles should be named in the symfony2 context.

It is advised to use `NamespaceProjectBundle`. This also documented. If you are stuck, [try generating a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html) via the `./app/console generate:bundle`. This way you can create a whole symfony2 structure which should show the default page hello/foo page just fine.

If it doesn't seem to run at all, make sure you have registered your bundle at the in the `app/AppKernel.php` file in the `registerBundles()` method.

Comment: thanks for everyone's help; have made some progress but no winner yet; need to stop for tonight but back on this tomorrow as it is very important for me.  all the best, G

Comment: thanks k0pernikus - I succeeded in creating a page; have a lot of other things to figure out so will be working on those...

Answer (score 1):

To configure routes you can use yml, php or xml file. You can specify it in app/config/config.yml

```
framework:
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
```

It's where you can check which file is used now.

Comment: Hello maniora:  thanks for helping.  I did check that file and it looks like it is  using the "routing.yml" file like you laid out.  So: I guess I need to add my route to that file and put nothing in "routing.php"?

Comment: thanks maniora - I succeeded in creating a page; have a lot of other things to figure out so will be working on those...

Comment: @gman_donster Please do not use the comment section to issue thank yous. You did that already by upvoting and accepting an answer :) The same goes for your comment on your question that you would readdress the issue. Comments are too provide feedback to a question/answer and to request clarification.

Answer (score 1):

There are some manners to store the routes.

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

This is how you use routes by writing annotations above your actions (eg indexAction) inside your controller class. [Read more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html).

Another common approach is to build one or more .yml files inside each Bundle.
in app/config/routing.yml you should write this:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Then you need to create the file (and directories if necessary) src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml and add the following content:

```
app_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

It will then try to find the DefaultController and fires the indexAction in the AppBundle (src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php).

To debug your routes simply type in your console from your projects directory:

```
app/console router:debug
```

Comment: thanks for everyone's help; have made some progress but no winner yet; need to stop for tonight but back on this tomorrow as it is very important for me.  all the best, G

Comment: thanks frankbeen - I succeeded in creating a page; have a lot of other things to figure out so will be working on those...